# When you edit dll in memory, do other applications see changes?

Tags: dll, process, kernel32, address-space

Let's say I'm editing kernel32.dll code in memory with Cheat Engine. I want to ask, when I edit it, is there any chance that there are other programs using the same address space where that dll is loaded? Or does each process get separate copy of the dll and you can change it however you want, yet the only crashes that may occur will be for that process only?